# How can I get Visual Studio to show merge conflicts under git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Pro and working with a Git repo.  Let's say I did a pull or applied stashed changes or did something that causes my branch to become in conflict.  For example, in this case I just applied a stash:

[image]

As you can see, I have a bunch of changes but Web.config is in conflict.  Why is it always the XML files that have the conflicts?

Now, I go into Visual Studio and go to *Team Explorer->Changes*:

[image]

Here, I see my staged changes, but there are *zero* unstaged changes.  I'm wondering why Web.config doesn't show up here so I can resolve the conflicts.

Two things:

1. I *believe* if I were to do a *Pull* using Visual Studio, it would detect the conflicts that then run the merge tool.  I haven't tried this yet, but I know it works that way for TFS.  However, I'd like to know if I can use *git pull* from the command line and then use Visual Studio to resolve conflicts.
2. `git config --global merge.tool` is already `vsdiffmerge` so if I were to run `git mergetool` from the command line, it would *then* use Visual Studio to merge.  However, doing this spawns a whole new instance of Visual Studio which is slow and annoying, and doesn't let me work in the context of the rest of my project.

Anyone have any insight on this one?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you managed to find a resolution to your problem? I find that VS sometimes recognizes that there are conflicts and sometimes not - doesn't seem to be any consistency so I haven't isolated any cause.

Comment: I have not.  I just use the command line for everything now.  I do believe VS2017 has _much_ better Git integration, but unfortunately we don't have the budget to upgrade.

Comment: @MikeChristensen keep in mind that the true and only one Git is in the command line. The GUIs try to be nice to you by hiding a lot of stuff in the background; but in the long term they do more harm than good. Or use a good GUI (e.g. Sourcetree) for resolving more complicated issues with the repo...

Comment: Does using a different editor work for you? You could try to use VS Code. It syncs up with files automatically, and shows conflicts. I realise this is not an answer to your question, but it could be a solution to this problem for someone.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.7.4 the *Changes* window seems to display the conflicts.

[image]

The setup:

```
/mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1>git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   ConsoleApp1/Class1.cs
        modified:   ConsoleApp1/Program.cs

/mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1>git stash apply
Auto-merging ConsoleApp1/Program.cs
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in ConsoleApp1/Program.cs
/mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1>git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   ConsoleApp1/Class1.cs

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:      ConsoleApp1/Program.cs

/mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1>
```

With colours:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Having a similar issue and getting this in Visual Studio

> Merge completed with conflicts in the '' repository. Resolve the
> conflicts and commit the results.

I tried the same as the previous answer, but the Team Explorer is removed in Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.8.4+. I was having the same troubles with the merge conflicts not showing and found that you need to commit the latest changes in the Git Changes window (no need to push yet) and **then** try to merge the changes that caused the conflict. At this point the unmerged changes appeared.

**TL;DR for VS2019**

1. Commit changes
2. Merge
3. Unmerged changes appears